# Make gcov recognize executions from shell script?

Tags: c, cmake, gcov

I'm using cmake and make to run tests by executing make test. Those tests include calling a shell script that runs the test programs 100 times with different content in a text file that those test programs read. Gcov doesn't recognize those 100 calls from the shellscript at all and so I do have bad test coverage even I know from the output and gdb that a lot more code has been tested. Is there any way to make gcov aware of my tests performed by the shell script? This is my shellscript:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((number=0;number < 100;number++))
{
echo "$number" > ./build/malloc.txt { ./build/malloc-test-$1; } &>> ./build/output-malloc-test-$1.txt
}

exit 0
```

Comment: Are the versions you're running properly instrumented?

Comment: I think so. I have two executables that run the same source file and I just recognized the problem might not be the shell script but lcov doesn't recognize the second target. Is there any way to make lcov use the coverage from multiple targets using the same source file?